# Which tools helps to start Ubuntu GUI when boot?

Tags: live-cd

I am on the way to create a Live CD from scratch. I used Virtual Box for this purpose. I installed Ubuntu base from ubuntumini.iso and installed gnome-shell. And installed Remastersys and created a backup.iso. Burned in a CD and boot from a PC. It end in CLI. Not lead to GUI. I tried the same ISO in VirtualBox. But it work properly there. I think I missed some packages which help to start GUI. Can you help me to identify the packages missed to include in the CD?

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu-desktop package should have depends on everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you use The **ubuntu minimum CD** with Remastersys that means you already have the GUI tools(all of them) so you don't have to install other tools.

Your problem is when you are booting you are foing to a page CLI just writing this

`(initframs)...`

I faced this problem before and tries many times and searched for many solutions and the problem stilled.

For that i decided to use another software. I found Relinux the best software to use instead of Remastersys.
 [Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux) is a great tutorial how to use.
Download the latest version from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/relinux/0.3/0.3.0a2/+download/relinux_0.3.0a2.tar.gz)

Comment: In my knowledge backup ISO is not with Relinux. Only distro is possible.

Comment: see the tutorail above